# Does PHP's mail() function prevent abuse?

Tags: php, email

I'm wondering if there is anything in place that will prevent me from accidentally destroying an email account. For example, let's say that I had the following code:

```
while(true){
    mail("me@website.com","subject","Message");
}
```

To me that script would forever email that account which seems like it would render that account effectively useless if it doesnt have good spam protection. Thoughts?

Comment: No, mail() dos not prevent this. Why would it? It is completely legitimate code.

Comment: Any e-mail sending function could be abused in this way, but of course you the programmer would have to write the code to do so. What’s more exploitable would be if a user of your web site could abuse the function. For example, if you allowed user-specified input to the fourth parameter, `$additional_headers` (not shown in your example), someone could exploit your mailer script to send spam to a destination of their choice.

Comment: most functions do as they are told and do not have the capacity to read minds and know what you 'really' meant, so if you tell it to send mail forever, it will obey. if you don't want something to happen forever, then don't let it get there. in the above case you'd have to flush the mail queue i believe to get rid of excess mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that code would do exactly as you say - send infinite emails to a particular account. The onus is on you as the developer to make sure that the code doesn't mess up in that way! Normally it's quite easy though, it's just using a bit of common sense to make sure you don't get sent a billion emails just saying "Message"...

Answer (score 0):

The `mail()` function is wide open to abuse which is why its use is generally discouraged in favour of libraries such as [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/).

While the php function itself has no spam protection, any decent email hosting service and/or email managing software would allow you to block the email address to prevent continuous spam.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the interactions with a database , and check at each iteration if you already sent a number of mails to the recepiant before you start bombing it . example :

```
define('_MAX_ALLOWED' , 5) ; 

while(true){
    if(getNumberOfMails("me@website.com") > _MAX_ALLOWED ) break ; 
    mail("me@website.com","subject","Message");
    saveMailToDatabase("me@website.com","subject","Message");
}
```